In my magento 2.4.7 project, on the checkout page after selecting the payment method, the place order button is disabled
In my magento 2.4.7 project, on the checkout page (I use swissup firecheckout) after selecting the payment method, the place order button is disabled and I cannot place the order. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Please check the JS error in the console. And provide a screenshot if any error display.
